# How do I get the AM/PM value from a just a Time not a date?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Why does this work,

```
@string.Format("{0:hh:mm:ss tt}", DateTime.Now)
```

But not this?

```
@string.Format("{0:hh:mm:ss tt}", worker.BegginingTime)
```

`worker.BegginingTime` is  a TimeSpan (edited due to comments) received from the database not a date.
How would I format just a TimeSpan correctly with am or pm?

Comment: What is typeof `worker.BegginingTime`?

Comment: Your description of *is just a time* is not precise enough. What class is it exactly?  Is it a string?  Is it a built-in type? What is it?

Comment: `System.TimeSpan` is the only class in .NET that stores just time.

Comment: @JonathanAllen what about `int`? It can store seconds or hours or minutes...

Comment: Edit you question to explain why the type is and then an answer can be given

Comment: What happens when the second example doesn't work?  Do you get a compile error?  A run-time exception?  An unexpected result?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov What if someone stored a string as an array of Int64?

Comment: @JonathanAllen why would not you edit the question to include proper [MCVE] since you somehow know what problem OP has? (It is perfectly fine now - http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/327373/should-i-edit-questions-to-an-mvce-for-the-users)

Comment: ADO.NET is completely idiotic because it maps `time` which has time-of-day semantics to `TimeSpan` which does not. I share your frustration. Mapping to a `DateTime` would have been more 1:1.

Comment: I'm ok with mapping `time` to `TimeSpan`. What bothers me is going the other direction, as `TimeSpan` includes days and `time` does not. I've had a lot of bugs over the years caused by that little annoyance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to convert it into a DateTime or write a custom formatter.

```
@string.Format("{0:hh:mm:ss tt}", new DateTime().Add(worker.BegginingTime))
```

---

Technically speaking TimeSpan doesn't store time of day, but rather duration.

Comment: As far as I can tell nobody has said that the type of the property is `TimeSpan`.  It could be a string: `"2:53"`

Answer (score -2):

Use

> string.Format("{0:t}", (DateTime)worker.BegginingTime))

Comment: "Cannot cast expression of type 'System.TimeSpan' to 'DateTime'."